# React Native 0.56 + Enzyme + Jest + React Navigation: Enzyme crashes because of import statement

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, enzyme

**TL;DR:** My tests crash, because of the following error linked to React Navigation:

```
/path-to-app/react-native/myApp/node_modules/react-navigation/src/views/withNavigation.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      127 | }
      128 |
    > 129 | export default withNavigation(
          |                                ^
      130 |   connect(
      131 |     null,
      132 |     { loginSuccess }

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
      at Object.get withNavigation [as withNavigation] (node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js:166:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/components/LoginForm/LoginForm.js:129:32)
```

The weird thing is that I use a named export, which is why React Navigation shouldn't even be loaded.

I'm trying to write unit tests for my login form. Here is the code for the form:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import { object as yupObject, string as yupString } from "yup";
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { loginSuccess } from "../../actions/login/login";
import alert from "../../api/alert/alert";
import { apiLoginUser } from "../../api/auth/auth";
import {
  BUTTON_TEXT_LOGIN,
  BUTTON_TEXT_FORGOTTEN_PASSWORD
} from "../../config/constants/buttonTexts";
import {
  ERROR_MESSAGE_INVALID_EMAIL_FORMAT,
  ERROR_MESSAGE_EMAIL_REQUIRED,
  ERROR_MESSAGE_PASSWORD_REQUIRED,
  ERROR_MESSAGE_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH
} from "../../config/constants/errorMessages";
import AuthInput from "../AuthInput/AuthInput";
import Button from "../Button/Button";
import ClearButton from "../ClearButton/ClearButton";
import styles from "./styles";

export class LoginForm extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.object,
    loginSuccess: PropTypes.func,
    isSubmitting: PropTypes.bool
  };

  handleSubmit = (values, formikBag) => {
    formikBag.setSubmitting(true);
    apiLoginUser(values.email, values.password)
      .then(data => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
        formikBag.setSubmitting(false);
        this.props.loginSuccess(data.user);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
        formikBag.setSubmitting(false);
      });
  };

  renderForm = (
    values,
    handleSubmit,
    setFieldValue,
    errors,
    touched,
    setFieldTouched,
    isValid,
    isSubmitting
  ) => (
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <AuthInput
        placeholder="Email address"
        value={values.email}
        onChange={setFieldValue}
        onTouch={setFieldTouched}
        name="email"
        error={touched.email && errors.email}
        editable={!isSubmitting}
      />
      <AuthInput
        placeholder="Password"
        value={values.password}
        onChange={setFieldValue}
        onTouch={setFieldTouched}
        name="password"
        error={touched.password && errors.password}
        editable={!isSubmitting}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <ClearButton
        text={BUTTON_TEXT_FORGOTTEN_PASSWORD}
        onPress={() => {}}
        containerStyles={styles.clearButtonContainer}
        buttonTextStyles={styles.clearButtonText}
      />
      <Button onPress={handleSubmit} disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting} loading={isSubmitting}>
        {BUTTON_TEXT_LOGIN}
      </Button>
    </View>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        validationSchema={yupObject().shape({
          email: yupString()
          .email(ERROR_MESSAGE_INVALID_EMAIL_FORMAT)
          .required(ERROR_MESSAGE_EMAIL_REQUIRED),
          password: yupString()
          .min(12, ERROR_MESSAGE_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH)
          .required(ERROR_MESSAGE_PASSWORD_REQUIRED)
        })}
        render={({
          values,
          handleSubmit,
          setFieldValue,
          errors,
          touched,
          setFieldTouched,
          isValid,
          isSubmitting
        }) =>
          this.renderForm(
            values,
            handleSubmit,
            setFieldValue,
            errors,
            touched,
            setFieldTouched,
            isValid,
            isSubmitting
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(
  connect(
    null,
    { loginSuccess }
  )(LoginForm)
);
```

And here is my test file:

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

import { LoginForm } from "./LoginForm";

describe("LoginForm", () => {
  describe("rendering", () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<LoginForm />);
    });

    it("should render a <View />", () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(View)).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see I'm using a named export to split the `LoginForm` from the `ConnectedLoginForm` which is connected to Redux and React Navigation. And still some part of Enzyme or Jest does not like React Navigation. Do you have any idea how to circumvent this problem?

### Edit 1

I managed to find a [workaround using a NavigationService.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html) It would still be awesome to know how to fix this, because this bug also prevents me from testing my screens that are using React Navigation.

### Edit 2

For anyone wondering [how to mock this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules), what I ended up doing was creating a `__mocks__` folder adjacent to the `node_modules` folder. In it I created a file called `react-navigation.js` in which I mocked all the behavior I needed to mock.

In the case of `withNavigation()` this meant just implementing a dummy [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html):

```
export const withNavigation = () => WrappedComponent => WrappedComponent;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could mock dependencies, such as navigation, like this:

```
jest.mock('react-navigation', () => ({ withNavigation: component => component}));
```

And then pass props, including navigation, to your component manually:

```
const mockProps = {
    navigation: { navigate: jest.fn() },
    loginSuccess: jest.fn(),
    isSubmitting: true
}
wrapper = shallow(<LoginForm {...mockProps}/>);
```

Comment: This seems to work for the components which are using `withNavigation()`. How would I go about the actual screens?

Comment: Have your sceens in separate files from where you create your navigator. Then you can test them like regular components. And for navigation creation just mock createStackNavigator, or whatever navigator, and assert what it was called with.

Comment: Wow Thank you very much for your help! I will test this and get back to you :)

Comment: I got this working for a snapshot test without Enzyme: `const mockProps = {
    navigation: { navigate: jest.fn() },
  }
  const tree = renderer.create(<MyScreen {...mockProps}/>).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});`